# Replacing char of a string in a list

Tags: python, string, replace

I got that:

```
state = (
    "#####   ",
    "###    #",
    "##  o ##",
    "   #####"
)
```

i need the "o" to move one to right

```
"##  o ##"
```

to

```
"##   o##"
```

the thing is that is has to be really robust for edge cases like:

```
"o ##"
```

I coded smth like that but its not gonna work like that...

```
def move(state, direction):
   
    for indx,i in enumerate(state):
        if "o" in i:
            line_indx= indx
            
    string_indx = state[line_indx].find("o")
    print(line_indx,string_indx)
    
    a=[]
    if direction.lower() == "rechts" and state[line_indx][string_indx+1] == " ":
        print("that would work")
        for i in state:
            if "o" not in i:
                a.append(i)
            elif "o" in i:
                a.append(i[:i.find("o")] + " o" + i[i.find("o")+1:])
```

I have to get rid of that slicing thing but don't know how...

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:
Output should look like this

```
state = (
    "#####   ",
    "###    #",
    "##   o##",
    "   #####"
)
```

E2:

```
a.append(i[:i.find("o")] + " " +"o"+ i[i.find("o")+2:])
```

works but there has to be a better solution...

Comment: Strings and tuples are immutable in Python. Can you represent the state as a list of lists instead? Then you can easily assign to individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `re` module for that following way:

```
import re
state = (
    "#####   ",
    "###    #",
    "##  o ##",
    "   #####"
)
new_state = tuple(re.sub(r"(o)(\s)", r"\2\1", i) for i in state)
print(new_state)
```

Output:

```
('#####   ', '###    #', '##   o##', '   #####')
```

Note that this will swap every `o` with whitespace to its right, for every `o` which have whitespace to its right. Explanation: I used so-called capturing groups and references for them.

Comment: crazy, thank you very much!! could you explain me the things inside the re.sub() or send me a link with explanations? I need to do it for different cases aswell (moving to left for example)

Comment: @Orsons: I suggest firstly to read [re.sub docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), then using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to understand this particular pattern

Answer (score 2):

I would say the easiest way to tackle this is by checking for each line if it contains an 'o'. If it does you want the line to be everything before the 'o' (`line[0:idx]`), then the 'o' prepended with a space (`" o"`) and then everything after the 'o', accounting for the newly added space (`line[idx + 2:]`).

```
state = (
    "#####   ",
    "###    #",
    "##  o ##",
    "   #####"
)
newstate = []

for line in state:
    if 'o' in line:
        idx = line.find('o')
        line = line[0:idx] + " o" + line[idx + 2:]
    newstate.append(line)

state = tuple(newstate)
print(state)
```

This will give the output:

```
('#####   ', '###    #', '##   o##', '   #####')
```

EDIT

I see in a comment you also want to be able to move left, etc. In that case you could replace the contents of the if-statement with a function call that processes the line accordingly, i.e.:

```
def left(line, idx):
    return line[0:idx - 1] + "o " + line[idx + 1:]

def right(line, idx):
    return line[0:idx] + " o" + line[idx + 2:]
```

And then inside the loop:

```
...
if 'o' in line:
    idx = line.find('o')
    line = left(line, idx)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to be able to move in all four directions and not just to the right.
In my opinion, it's easier to work with mutable sequences for such types of problems (As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) suggested).
I.e. use a nested `List` as state instead of the immutable `tuple` of `str`s.
If you're not able to change the function signature, you can use type casts like so:

```py
import typing as t
from enum import Enum

State = t.Tuple[str, ...]
Position = t.Tuple[int, int]


class Direction(str, Enum):
    up = "up"
    down = "down"
    left = "left"
    right = "right"


def get_position(state: State) -> Position:
    o_indices = [(x, y) for x, row in enumerate(state) for y, item in enumerate(row) if item == "o"]
    assert len(o_indices) == 1, "There must be exactly one o."
    return o_indices[0]


def move(state: State, direction: Direction) -> State:
    x, y = old_x, old_y = get_position(state)

    if direction == "down":
        x += 1
    elif direction == "up":
        x -= 1
    elif direction == "right":
        y += 1
    elif direction == "left":
        y -= 1

    # Assert validity of move:
    assert 0 <= x < len(state), "Trying to move out of field vertically."
    assert 0 <= y < len(state[0]), "Trying to move out of field horizontally."
    assert state[x][y] != "#", "Trying to move into fence."

    # This would be easier with a MutableSequence, i.e. if state was a nested List
    new_state = list(list(row) for row in state)
    new_state[x][y] = "o"
    new_state[old_x][old_y] = " "

    return tuple("".join(row) for row in new_state)
```

Test for the following assumptions pass:

- Moving right into a blank space works ( ).
- You should not be able to move out of the field to the right.
- You should not be able to move right into a `#`.

You should also check for the other edge cases.

```py
def test_move_right():
    state = (
        "#####   ",
        "###    #",
        "##  o ##",
        "   #####"
    )

    expected_state = (
        "#####   ",
        "###    #",
        "##   o##",
        "   #####"
    )

    new_state = move(state, Direction.right)
    assert new_state == expected_state


def test_move_right_blocked():
    state = (
        "#####   ",
        "###    #",
        "##   o##",
        "   #####"
    )

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        move(state, Direction.right)


def test_move_right_out():
    state = (
        "#####  o",
        "###    #",
        "##    ##",
        "   #####"
    )

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        move(state, Direction.right)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It helped me a lot, I just forgot to upvote it... sorry

Answer (score 0):

if you want "## o #" to be converted as "## o#" here is the code. Assuming "state" is list as you have mentioned "list" in the question

```
for indx,i in enumerate(state):
    if "o " in i:
            line_indx= indx
            state[indx]=i.replace("o ","o")
print(state)
```

Comment: `state` is clearly a tuple. As tuples are immutable your solution will not work. Also where did you get the variable `l` from?